# When does Pokérus in Pokemon Moon have a chance of being cured: midnight game time or midnight system time?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

#### Summary

I haven't played a standard pokemon game since Generation 1 until recently when I picked up Pokemon Moon. A friend traded me some pokemon infected with Pokérus to help me get started, but I accidentally let all my infected pokemon become immune, and I'm not sure exactly when the immunity triggered.

#### Findings So Far

According to [this IGN article](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-sun-pokemon-moon/Pokerus):

> "After one to four days (at midnight), Pokerus will no longer be contagious..."

However, since Pokemon Moon is timeshifted by 12 hours with respect to the 3DS system time, I am not sure if "midnight" in this context would be applied based on the 3DS system time (i.e. "real life time") hitting midnight; or "midnight" in Pokemon Moon which would be Noon IRL.

I also tried [searching existing questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpokemon-sm%5D+pokerus), but couldn't find any results that matched my question at the time of writing this question.

#### Educated (unconfirmed) Guess

If I had to guess, I'd lean towards it triggering at midnight based on system/real-life time; just because the player is more likely to be asleep rather than at noon; but I've been unable to find confirmation of this.

Can anyone confirm the exact timing that Pokérus has a chance of becoming cured in Pokemon Moon?

Comment: If it was the system time that could trivially be exploited, just chnage the time zone, at 2359 to a time zone where it's 0101...

Comment: Well, even if it was based off the shifted time in-game, you could (possibly) just shift the game clock anyways, since the game time is derived from the system time; though perhaps there's some feature to prevent players from trying this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pokérus is working with the **in-game** time. Reading the [wiki page](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9rus) about Pokérus:

> Whenever the **game's internal clock** strikes midnight, every currently infected Pokémon in the player's party has their Pokérus value decreased by one. Once the Y value reaches 0, the Pokémon will be cured of Pokérus.

So for Pokémon Moon, you have to take the 12 hours shift in account. You can get the actual in-game time by asking the coffee shop vendor in any Pokémon Center.

Comment: Guess I need to make a habit of banking my infected Pokemon before lunchtime!

Comment: Just an additional note that I can confirm (double-confirm?) your answer in my testing; I had some fresh infectees that had pokérus before noon yesterday (IRL time) and by the afternoon they were cured. 

Thankfully this time I spread the infection far and wide, and set some designated infectors to keep in the box so it's not a problem now.