# When a Pokemon gets infected by Pokerus, does it inherit the Pokerus' days left to be cured?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-seventh-generation

Last night I was capturing and infecting low level Pokemon to give away on Wonder Trade.

I was using an infected Hypno as an infection source, this Hypno contracted Pokerus 3 days ago (and decremented its counter to 1 by being on the party on the date roll over)

When doing the wonder trades the clock hit the 00:00, and newly infected Pokemon were suddenly cured, even when they where just infected a few minutes prior.

The thing that puzzles me its that i was playing Pokemon Moon so the day reset should have been on at noon not at midnight (as mentioned on [When does Pokérus in Pokemon Moon have a chance of being cured: midnight game time or midnight system time?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/296234/))

So, is this a glitch, or are the "days to cure" inheritable? The entries on Bulbapedia an Serebii don't mention this at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pokerus is contagious for 1 - 4 days, this is random, not inherited. So even if your hypno was contagious for three days, a new pokemon freshly infected might just be contagious for one.